# MySQL save INTO OUTFILE on Local Machine

Tags: mysql, into-outfile, sqlyog

I have a SQL connection to a remote SQL server and would like to run a query where the results are stored in a outfile. The problem is i want to have the file saved locally on my machine.

How would i go about doing that?

Comment: You cannot do that, file cannot be saved on your local machine, but can be saved on a directory shared via samba or something

Comment: thanks man, was worried about that

Answer (score 0):

Run the query, fetch the results in a array and store the array to a text file on your machine.

Answer (score -2):

you can run this:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p -e "SELECT * FROM database.table;">C:\result.txt
```